# Como retirar dtype de linha do dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Rodando o código:

```
def novacoluna(df):
  coluna_adicionada = {}
  coluna_adicionada['retorno_diario']= df['quota_value']/df['quota_deslocada']
  return pd.Series(coluna_adicionada, index=['retorno_diario'])

agrupamento_por_fundo = df.groupby([df['fund_name'], df['date']]).apply(novacoluna)
```

Para adicionar uma nova coluna ao dataframe agrupado, quando rodo agrupamento_por_fundo.head() os dados aparecem dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra poder adicionar na coluna apenas os resultados da conta, sem 10397 antes e o dtype depois?

Comment: pq vc criou uma função para adicionar coluna? Tenta criar a coluna diretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criar uma coluna como resultado de outras duas é mais simple do que parece

### Crie o DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'quota_value': [10.10, 20.0, 15.50, 50.0], 'quota_deslocada': [2, 2, 5, 5]})

>>> df
   quota_value  quota_deslocada
0         10.1                2
1         20.0                2
2         15.5                5
3         50.0                5
```

### Crie a nova coluna baseada nas outras duas

```
>>> df['retorno_diario'] = df['quota_value']/df['quota_deslocada']

>>> df
   quota_value  quota_deslocada  retorno_diario
0         10.1                2            5.05
1         20.0                2           10.00
2         15.5                5            3.10
3         50.0                5           10.00
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 1):

O problma é que a sua função cria uma série com os dados que você precisa,
e na sequência você cria um dataframe  contendo a série, na linha que tem o "return".  Na resposta o conteúdo de cada célula é ele mesmo uma série completa, e a representação da série inclui a informação de 'dtype'.

Sua função poderia ser só:

```
def novacoluna(df):
  
  coluna_adicionada = df['quota_value']/df['quota_deslocada']
  coluna_adicionada.name = 'retorno_diario'
  return coluna_adicionada
```